# Doing same task in Batch instead of PowerShell: iterate all users and find %temp% folder to delete files inside

Tags: powershell, batch-file, temp

I have a powershell script that works as such: it deletes any files or folders within C:\users\%user1,2,3...etc%\temp. It goes through each user in users folder and finds if it has a temp folder then deletes stuff inside.

I need to know whats the best way to have this be done in Batch to avoid compatibility issues?

```
$users = Get-ChildItem C:\Users
foreach ($user in $users){
$folder = "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\temp"
   If (Test-Path $folder) {
     Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Include * | remove-Item -recurse 
   }
}
```

Comment: In general, if you *CAN* use PS (vs. .bat), then you probably *SHOULD* use PS.Q: What "compatibility issues"?  Exactly where *CAN'T* you run Powershell?

Comment: The scripts are going to be run through Connectwise Automate, we already have a .bat script to run other temp file cleanups, we have to integrate this with the rest. It becomes a pain real fast across hundreds of computers to make sure each one can execute PS scripts.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: why *wouldn't* a Windows PC be able to run Powershell?  Because it happens to be Windows 95 (or older)?  Or "something else"?  Isn't PS part of your "standard build" for Windows workstations and servers?

Comment: Can your organization use a GPO (Group Policy Object) to enable PowerShell script execution? https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/

Comment: My main problem is that I can't change the entire system and how its setup. I will have to use .bat scripts until we can all agree here to stop using Batch. So not a hardware/software limitation, but more of a people limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in a batch file to loop through C:\USERS and remove items in the TEMP folder:

```
for /d %%F in (c:\users\*) do del "%%F\appdata\local\temp\*" /s /q
```

If you run this at a command line, use just one percent sign, when using it a batch file, use two percent signs.

This command loops over all directories in C:\USERS, and then runs a DEL against the AppData\Local\Temp folder, using silent and recursive parameters.  This assumes that your user profiles are stored in C:\USERS, if you have reason to need to look for profiles everywhere, you'll want to adjust your batch file to find the profile paths from the registry first.

As with all code you find online, test before running in production.

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: @Kiril - I'm glad to hear that, could you please accept my answer?